# How to read pair in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm having little trouble with reading pair.

So I'm creating my pair

```
private Pair<Integer, Integer> count(somethink) {
    int c1 = 2;
    int c2 = 4;
    return new Pair<Integer, Integer>(c1, c2);

}
```

And 'sending' it to ftl via java

```
mv.addObject("counted", count(somethink));
```

I won't write everything how it sends because I don't think it really matters with my issue. So i'm recieving it in "ftl". Then I was trying to 'read' it.

```
<#list counted?keys as key> 
    <a href="#offerOrderTab"><@spring.message "someMsg"/>(${key}/${counted[key]})</a>
</#list>
```

After then I'm getting error

```
Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression x is instead a freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel
```

As I suppose you don't iterate pairs (or I'm wrong?) I know its pair that contains only one key and one value but still I have to do send it that way and I thought its going be to similar to iterating through map, in Java I would use pair.first() and pair.second() but it doesn't work in ftl (yes I know it shouldn't work). I also tried to cast it to String by using `?string` but it didnt work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried?

```
${counted.first()?xml}/${counted.second()?xml}
```

Assuming `pair.first()` and `second()` work in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the API of `Pair` looks, but with `?keys` you probably unwillingly list its methods. Hence the error message; you try to print the method itself, not its return value. (As of the broken error message, because there's no `x` there, a FreeMarker update would help.) So as Caleryn says, just call the two methods. If you need to list this thing, you probably need to put it into a `List` or array, unless `Pair` implements `List` (or even just `Collection`) or `Iterable`. Or if this is a bigger issue in your project, FreeMarker has this pluggable configuration component, the `ObjectWrapper`, and with that you can tell FreeMarker to treat `Pair`-s as lists, and how. That needs *some* deeper understanding of FreeMarker though.

Comment: -1 on my FreeMarker answer! :) Why BTW? Oh, I guess I have figured. I'm not kidding with the method listing. Many FreeMarker setups use pure `BeansWrapper`, and that thing lists the methods and properties of objects mixed together with `?keys`.